# How react hook form update the field array without using setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I using react hook form, and using field array. From my understanding, useFieldArray allows you to manage dynamic array of fields. We dont need a custom onChange function when input is changed, it will update automatically.

What im trying to do:
i would like to generate a log with old value and new value when the qty is changed and onBlur. Im able to get the oldValue, just the new value.

Here's my initial value:

```
const initialValues = {
  items: [{ qty: 2, cost: 10 }]
};
```

But i tried the way bellow, it doesnt work. When the input is change, it doesnt update the field array data. it remains the initial value.

```
const handleBlurQty = (event, data, index, oldValue) => {
  console.log(data.qty) // doesn't it refer to `items.${index}.qty`? 
}

render: (data, index) => {
    return (
    <CustomTextField
        name={`items.${index}.qty`}
        onBlur={(event, oldValue) => {
          handleBlurQty(event, data, index, oldValue);
        }}
    />
)}
```

**CustomTextField.js**

```
const { field } = useController({ name });

const oldValueRef = useRef(field?.value);

const _handleChange = (event) => {
  oldValueRef.current = event?.target?.defaultValue;
  field.onChange(event);
};

const _handleBlur = (event) => {
  onBlur(event, oldValueRef.current);
};

<TextField
    {...register(name)}
    onBlur={_handleBlur}
    onChange={_handleChange}
    value={field.value}
/>
```

I've no idea how to fix this, please help :(